# Access SMB shares using stored credentials

Tags: samba, authentication

Assuming I have a network of a few Windows computers, and I set up the same user with the same password on all computers, this user will be able to access any shares on any of the computers - without entering his credentials a second time after having successfully logged on.

Now I'm adding a Linux box to the picture. Samba is installed, smbtree properly shows all computers in the workgroup. The same user with the same password as on the windows boxes was set up on this Linux box and also in Samba itself, using smbpasswd -A {user}.

But that doesn't seem to work as expected. When I try to access one of the windows shares, I'm being asked to provide a password. Sure enough, I could save those credentials in a plain text file and reuse but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to access simple SMB shares, on computers in a workgroup, reusing the credentials already stored in /etc/passwd or in the local Samba user db?

Comment: If you manually created the users on all of the machines then they aren't the same user. Windows identifies users by SID whereas Linux identifies then by UID. The SID will be different on all the Windows machines and the UID on the Linux machine won't be recognized by Windows. This is why you are being prompted when accessing the shares via the Linux machine and you will also be prompted when accessing the shares from one of the Windows machines. The best way to accomplish what you're doing is to set up and LDAP server for authentication and create a group for all of the members.

Comment: Ran out of characters above: To add to it, you can create a fileserver and export the shares as NFS and create ACLs using LDAP for authentication. It's extremely difficult to do what you need in the state that you have things.

Comment: True, the SID isn't the same but you can still access the shares without being prompted for credentials as long as it's all Windows.

Comment: That's assuming that you've turned off password protected sharing but that's not the case by default. If you've done that, then there's no reason to create the same user on every machine but that's irrelevant here as that's a Windows issue. In your case, there isn't any way to achieve what you're trying to do because you'll have to authenticate with Linux to mount the Windows shares whether using the command line or the GUI. There is no way to do what you want unless you store a password in a file and pass it to `/etc/fstab` to mount the drive which is a potential security issue.